# Reading specific column from CSV and converting to double for further calculations in Java

Tags: java

I have a CSV file (fixed 43 columns and rows vary each time) which contains String and double values in it. I need to fetch values from 12th (NetPrice) and 13th (Tax) columns which are actually double values. I need to add (NetPrice + Tax) at each row, until end of CSV file and get the total amount. I am able to fetch the values as String format but while trying to convert to double, I am facing NumberFormatExeption. I understood that there is some mistake in conversion, but I am unable to identify it. Request to help for the same. Below is my code.

I have found one solution for a similar problem in SO but it didn't help me, so posting my question.

**Sample CSV file**

[image]

At the end, I need to add again all the above added amount to get the final total price as highlighted in above image.

public void getTotalPrice() throws IOException 
    {

```
    String csvFile = "file path";
    String line ;
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";
    String NetPrice;
    String Tax;
    double FinalTotal = 0.00;

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile))) 
    {
        br.readLine();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            String[] Amount = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
            NetPrice = Amount[11]; //hold 12th column value
            Tax = Amount[12]; //hold 13th column value
            double NP = Double.parseDouble(NetPrice); //convert String to double
            double T = Double.parseDouble(Tax); //convert string to double
            FinalTotal = FinalTotal + (NP+T); //calculation for getting final price
        }

    }catch(NumberFormatException n)
    {
        n.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Below is the Error I am facing:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""78.63""
```

From the error message I understood that the string value that is trying to get parsed to double is reading with extra double quotes """"

Comment: why are you trying to create csv parser of your own, there are many existing solutions that do this plus, many more things. I have used http://super-csv.github.io/super-csv/index.html in past and never regretted the decision.

Comment: Seconded. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/ is another option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the quotations from the `String` before you parse it as a number. I would also recommend using `BigDecimal` object when working with numerical values such as currency like in your case.

***Code***

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String csvFile = "file path";
    String line;
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";
    String netPrice;
    String tax;
    BigDecimal finalTotal = BigDecimal.ZERO;

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile))) {
        br.readLine();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] Amount = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

            netPrice = Amount[11]; //hold 12th column value
            netPrice = netPrice.replace("\"", "");
            BigDecimal netPriceBd = new BigDecimal(netPrice);

            tax = Amount[12]; //hold 13th column value
            tax = tax.replace("\"", "");
            BigDecimal taxBd = new BigDecimal(tax);

            BigDecimal total = netPriceBd.add(taxBd);

            finalTotal = finalTotal.add(total);
        }

    } catch (NumberFormatException n) {
        n.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Garreth.... It worked.
I came to know about BigDecimal today, thanks for that too.

Comment: Glad it helped. Can you accept the answer if you're happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Tax` is a string you can apply a method to it which checks, if it is not null and then removes the quotes (and eventually other non numeric characters) and then parses it to a double. Something along these lines:

```
private static double convertToDouble(String str) {
    if(str == null || str.trim().isEmpty()) {
        return 0.0;
    }
    return Double.parseDouble(str.replaceAll("[^\\d\\.]", ""));
}
```

You can quickly test this method using this code here:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {

    System.out.println(convertToDouble("\"78.63\""));
    System.out.println(convertToDouble("\"7.63\"  "));
    System.out.println(convertToDouble(null));
    System.out.println(convertToDouble("    "));
    System.out.println(convertToDouble(" 2.123"));
}
```

This will print out:

```
78.63
7.63
0.0
0.0
2.123
```

Comment: Thanks a lot gil, this worked for me. 
But in middle of calculation the decimal places of the total suddenly growing to 13 digits and for the next calculation, it automatically shrinks to 2 decimal places. And finally, the total is showing with 13 decimal places as 4033.5799999999995 (which I can shrink to 2 decimal places at the end using round function)

Comment: @rvsk If this was useful for you, you can consider to accept this answer. This will increase your reputation.